# For which purpose the events pattern declares the event firerer method as virtual?

Tags: c#, events

I am trying to understand for which purpose the events pattern decided that the method that fires the event should be declared virtual.

From [C#6 in a Nutshell, from Joseph and Ben Albahari, O'Reilley](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920040323.do):

> Finally, the pattern requires that you write a protected virtual method that fires the
>   event. The name must match the name of the event, prefixed with the word On, and
>   then accept a single EventArgs argument:

Below a snippet I created to try to investigate.
I had the impression that the idea was to allow inheriting classes to **completely** overwrite how the event is handled, out of the box (original class). But the snippet below shows this is not possible, because deriving classes will never be able to invoke the event objects themselves (by the one one of the goals of the constraints imposed by the keyword event on delegates). The event can be invoked only in the containing class.

Now, since the pattern also asks that the method that fires the event simply check if the the event is not null and then call the delegate, with whatever every subscriber asked to do, what is left to be achieved by having the method that fires the event as virtual ? Inheriting classes are obliged to invoke the event the way it is in the broadcaster class, so all that is left for them is to add functionality. But this is exactly what they can achieve by subscribing to the event, in other words, by adding a call to an external function the time the event is fired.

I hope my wording is clear enough.

```
namespace eventsPatternVirtualEventFirerer
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var obj = new X();

            obj.ev += Obj_ev;
            obj.Start();
        }

        private static void Obj_ev(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("subscriber code...");
        }
    }

    public class X
    {
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> ev;

        protected virtual void OnEvent(EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("original implementation...");
            ev?.Invoke(this, e);
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            OnEvent(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public class X2 : X
    {
        public X2()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnEvent(EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("inheriting class implementation overwrite...");
            //compilation error - "the event 'X.ev' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= (except when used from within the type 'X')"
            ev?.Invoke(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the purpose is to allow derived classes to do something before/after the event is fired

```
public class X2 : X
{
    public X2()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnEvent(EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do something before the event
        base.OnEvent(e);
        // Do something after the event
    }
}
```

There are a few things you can add/change in a derived class

- Add a `OnBeforeEvent` / `OnAfterEvent` addition.
- Choose not to broadcast the event (by conditionally not calling `base.OnEvent(e)`).
- Vary the event args in some way.

Additionally, If you think about the way something like a page model works, it typically fires a `Load` event to notify when the page is loaded. Without a `protected OnLoad` method, derived classes would have to subscribe to it's own `Load` event to perform some action on load

```
public class MyPage : Page
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        // do something when the page is loaded
         base.OnLoad(e);
    }

}
```

versus:

```
public class MyPage : Page
{
    public MyPage() : base()
    {
         this.Load += (sender,e) => {
             // bleugh - subscribing to my own events 
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: oh... looks like this is what I missed. What about all those third party components that provide "OnBefore..." and "OnAfter..." or alikes. Are they redundant, in that you could yourself achieve the results by doing the above, assuming everybody follows the pattern as it was defined ?

Comment: suppressing and filtering is also an option. override and don't call (or conditionally call) `base.OnEvent`

Comment: @dlatikay: but if you do not call base.OnEvent, how will the delegates be called, if only the broadcaster can do that ?

Comment: @Veverke I think the point is your derived class may choose to *not* broadcast the event

Comment: Additional: without this method a derived class might need to subscribe to its own events, a little clumsy and inefficient.

Comment: @Jamiec: I am trying to understand your last comment, but am struggling with my understanding of the purpose of the pattern in the first place: Hello world, I am a broadcaster, and I do something. And I would like to tell the world, that, if anyone is interested in this something I do (in case it needs to take actions before, after this something happens), please subscribe and you will be informed of when it happens, so you can take action. Now you say some classes may opt not to be informed whatsoever.

Comment: Continuing:  well, this means that ultimately this class is interested in all the other functionalities of the broadcaster class, but not in that something it does ? Thus making the point of still inheriting from it, but not being interested in the broadcasting ?

Comment: No, some *broadcaster* may decide it doesnt *want* to broadcast.

Comment: @Veverke Ive created a [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173116/veverke-event-broadcasting-q) which is probably better for discussion if you want to

Comment: To be fair, a class that suppresses events this way would be rare and getting close to violating the substitution principle.

Comment: I agree with @bommelding - you *can* do it, doesnt mean its a good idea!

Answer (score 1):

A good example might be the Paint event in Windows Forms.

```
// in MyButton : BaseButton : Control

void override OnPaint(object s, PaintEveargs e)
{
   base.OnPaint(s, e); // Control: Draw background, BaseButton: draw border
   // draw my own stuff
}
```

A button has several layers of base class, each drawing on top of each other.